# how to get a final snapshot for a react component after fetching datas?

Tags: jestjs

I'm testing a react component UI. Within this component, a request is sent and fetch data to rerender UI. Now a snapshot before the request fetch data is produced. How to get a snapshot after the request?

```
// component.js
class Text extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {   
    this.load()   
  }

  load = () => {
    const {id} = this.props
    fetch('/abc').then(data => {
      this.setState({data})
    })
  }

  render() {
    if(!this.state.data) return null
    const {data} = this.state

    return (
      <div>
       {data}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```
//jest
describe('test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetch.mockImplementation(()=> new Promise(resolve=>resolve(4)))
  });



  test('base render', async () => {
    const wrapper = await render(<Text/>)
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot()
  })


})
```

```
//received snapshot
null
```

```
//expected snapshot
<div>
  4
</div>
```